# How to share snippet between typescript and typescriptreact?

Tags: filetype, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I use `UltiSnips` to manage my snippets and I have a few snippets in `typescriptreact` but I'm not able to use them in `typescript`.

Is there a way to share snippets between them?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to share snippets:

1. Using a dotted filetype
2. Using `extends`

For the first method, set the dotted filetype with

```
:set ft=typescriptreact.typescript
```

and you can use both `typescriptreact` and `typescript` snippets for the current buffer.
(See the end of the section `:h UltiSnips-how-snippets-are-loaded` for details)

The second method allows the use of both snippets for *all* files of a certain filetype (not just for a certain buffer). To use `typescriptreact` snippets in a `typescript` file, add the line

```
extends typescriptreact
```

to the `typescript` snippets file. Now, when UltiSnips activates snippets for a `typescript` file, it looks for all `typescripteact`
snippets and activates them as well.
(See the top of `:h UltiSnips-basic-syntax` for details)